# How can I call StackNavigator from a class component in React Native?

Tags: react-router, navigation, react-native, react-navigation-v5

Im trying to make a Hello World page with a link to a details page. I get how to navigate using functional components using StackNavigator. But I'm confused on how it works from a class component. Im using react navigation 5.x and React Native 0.61
How to translate this into the class based component syntax ( as most tutorials follow that and not the new functional component).

When we use functional components - as of React Native 0.61 - the method is to do this :

```
function WelcomePage({ navigation }) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.heading} >Welcome!</Text>
        </View>
      )
}
```

But when I try to do this in a class - how do I make it call or inherit from navigation ?

```
export default class HelloWorld extends Component<Props> {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details') }><Text>Go to Details</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

It gives me this error (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujGlx.png)). Am I supposed to bind 'this' or something, whenever I try this.something it again throws similar errors. Is this something related to the new version 0.61 of React native and lack of backward compatibility - or what is it ?

Answer (score 0):

The navigation comes from props

```
 //                       props
 function WelcomePage({ navigation }) { ... }
```

To access the props in class component, you do `this.props.navigation`.

In your example, it would be

```
export default class HelloWorld extends Component<Props> {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
        {/*                                 getting navigation from props*/}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details') }><Text>Go to Details</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Please read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) about props.